# In WINFORM, listView ColumnWidthChanging event is not fire OR alternate to disable resize column

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

I have added list view control using .NET 4.5.

My list view control's mode is set to DETAILS view

and registered event as below on constructor as well as on load event after populating list view .

```
AddHandler lvResult.ColumnWidthChanging, AddressOf lvResult1_ColumnWidthChanging
```

also, on design time, created on changing event.

This event is never called. i abled to get call `ColumnWidthChanged` event but changing not called.

Please suggest what is wrong ?

I need this for DISABLE THE COLUMN RESIZING IN LISTVIEW. if you know any alternative way to disable column resizing then please share me. ?

Thank YOu

Answer (score 1):

The ColumnWidthChanging event seems unreliable at best. I've seen the same thing with VB 2008. I'm not sure what the solution is for ColumnWidthChanging, but here's a decent workaround (if you'll pardon my VB). Just set the column width back to the original value in the Changed event. I used an arbitrary value of 90 here, but you can use a list or array with the proper column widths.

```
Private Sub ListView1_ColumnWidthChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ColumnWidthChanged
Static busy As Boolean = False
If busy Then Exit Sub
busy = True
ListView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Width = 90
busy = False
End Sub
```

Comment: HOw this busy variable work.  Basically, there are 10 columns and only 2 are visible and all other are 0 width.

Comment: When you change the value of the column width, it fires the ColumnWidthChamged event again. The variable Busy prevents infinite recursion and stackoverflow.